# Joining two tables on two criteria "cannot partition on repeated field"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, flatten

I'm using BigQuery for this.

I have a subquery that pulls data from a table that has an account_id, product, date, and product_spend fields. This subquery calculates the total lifetime spend for each product for each 'account_id' by adding up each of the line items.

```
SELECT  account_id,
        product,
        SUM(product_spend)/1000000 lifetime_product_spend

FROM    usage
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

The result looks like this:

```
table: lifetime                        
account_id         product          lifetime_product_spend                
===========================================================         
    A              product1              50
    A              product2              20   
    B              product2              100
    B              product3              150
    C              product3              500
```

I'm trying to **preserve the values** and join them with a larger query:

```
SELECT  account_id,
        product,
        month,
        SUM(spend)

FROM data_source
WHERE month >= DATE_ADD(today ,-5,"MONTH")
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

This query has a table that looks like this:

```
table: monthly                        
account_id         product              month            spend             
=================================================================
    A              product1              1                10
    A              product1              2                20
    A              product1              3                30
    A              product2              1                5
    A              product2              2                15
    B              product2              2                100
    B              product3              2                100
    B              product3              3                50
    C              product3              1                100
    C              product3              2                400
```

I'm not using an aggregate to calculate lifetime_product_spend on the second table. Due to the sheer amount of data, I'm only able to include the last 6 months data. That's why I'm calculating the lifetime spend in a different table and joining them.

My current query is failing:

```
SELECT  d.account_id,
        d.product,
        d.month,
        sum(d.spend),
        u.lifetime_product_spend
FROM data_source d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  account_id,
           product,
           SUM(product_spend)/1000000 lifetime_product_spend
           FROM usage
           GROUP BY account_id, product) u
ON d.account_id = u.account_id
WHERE d.month >= DATE_ADD(today ,-5,"MONTH")
GROUP BY d.account_id, d.product, d.month, u.lifetime_product_spend
```

because it doesn't seem to have assigned the lifetime figures to each product as in the Lifetime table. That's because I'm only joining on account_id. See below for the bad output. I've truncated this table because it basically added the # of outputs I have for lifetime_product_spend (5) and put one for each month, product, and company...because it's ignoring the 'product' assignment for these values:

```
table: monthly                        
account_id         product           month         spend      lifetime_product_spend       
=====================================================================================
    A              product1           1             10                   50
    A              product1           1             10                   20
    A              product1           1             10                   100
    A              product1           1             10                   150
    A              product1           1             10                   500
    A              product1           2             20                   50
    A              product1           2             20                   20
    A              product1           2             20                   100
    A              product1           2             20                   150
    A              product1           2             20                   500
```

Is there a way for me to join on both of them? I've tried doing a JOIN ON x = x AND y = y:

```
SELECT  d.account_id,
        d.product,
        d.month,
        sum(d.spend),
        u.lifetime_product_spend
FROM data_source d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  account_id,
           product,
           SUM(product_spend)/1000000 lifetime_product_spend
           FROM usage
           GROUP BY account_id, product) u
ON (d.account_id = u.account_id AND d.product = u.product)
WHERE d.month >= DATE_ADD(today ,-5,"MONTH")
GROUP BY d.account_id, d.product, d.month, u.lifetime_product_spend
```

but it gives me this error : "Execution Failed
Error: Cannot partition on repeated field d.product".
I want my final table to look like this:

```
table: monthly                        
account_id         product           month         spend      lifetime_product_spend       
=====================================================================================
    A              product1           1             10                   50
    A              product1           2             20                   50
    A              product1           3             30                   50
    A              product2           1             5                    20
    A              product2           2             15                   20
    B              product2           2             100                  100
    B              product3           2             100                  150
    B              product3           3             50                   150
    C              product3           1             100                  500
    C              product3           2             400                  500
```

I think I need "FLATTEN" somewhere, but I can't seem to get it in the right place. Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: Hi @Blorgbeard . Thanks for commenting. I've updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  d.account_id,
        d.product,
        d.month,
        sum(d.spend),
        u.lifetime_product_spend
FROM FLATTEN(data_source, product) d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  account_id,
           product,
           SUM(product_spend)/1000000 lifetime_product_spend
           FROM usage
           GROUP BY account_id, product) u
ON (d.account_id = u.account_id AND d.product = u.product)
WHERE d.month >= DATE_ADD(today ,-5,"MONTH")
GROUP BY d.account_id, d.product, d.month, u.lifetime_product_spend
```

The above works with the original data source flattened around the repeated field d.product. Thanks for the comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

Write "Select .... from usage" as a sub-query and apply an INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN on data_source table.

```
SELECT  d.account_id,
        d.product,
        d.month,
    sum(d.spend),
    u.lifetime_product_spend
from data_source d
 left join (SELECT  account_id,
        product,
        SUM(product_spend)/1000000 lifetime_product_spend
         FROM usage
          GROUP BY account_id, product) u
  on(d.account_id=u.account_id and d.product=u.product)
WHERE d.month >= DATE_ADD(today ,-5,"MONTH")
GROUP BY d.account_id, d.product, d.month, u.lifetime_product_spend
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I tried that and got:

Execution Failed
Error: Cannot partition on repeated field d.product

Comment: I think I need a "FLATTEN" somewhere, but I can't seem to get it in the right place.

Comment: It looks like BigQuery supports only a subset of standard SQL.